# SQL Preserve the Order in group by

Tags: sql-server, query, group-by, order-by

I have records like below in my table.

[image]

I want distinct records and when I do group by it loses the Order. I want to maintain the order. I have written below query to get the desired however its not working:

```
 select route_id,fixcode,fixdescription from 
 route_fixcodes group by route_id,fixcode,fixdescription
 having route_id = 12345 Order by fixcode
```

I want Result like below:

[image]

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[route_fixcodes](
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [route_id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [fixcode] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
  [fixdescription] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK__route_fi__3213E83FD7609D27] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
```

Comment: Can you please post the query that you are using for group by.

Comment: select route_id,fixcode,fixdescription from route_fixcodes group by route_id,fixcode,fixdescription having route_id = 12345 Order by fixcode

Comment: What is the use of group by here when there is no any aggregate function? can you also please include DDL of route_fixcodes table.

Comment: group by is used to get distinct records. DDL route_fixcodes
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[route_fixcodes](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [route_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [fixcode] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
 [fixdescription] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__route_fi__3213E83FD7609D27] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

Comment: What is the actual order you want? Looking at the screenshots, data is not ordered numerically by fix code, or alphabetically by fixdescription, in your expected output. What column do you want to order the data by?

Comment: Actually, I don't want output by in any of column order. I want output as it is in my DB table or screenshot given. ya, looking at the screenshot, data is not ordered.

Comment: Data in SQL Server has no guaranteed order.  Whatever order it happened to have been returned in your first query, it could be different the next time you run that exact query.  In practice, data will *often* come back in the order of the clustering index - but that's contingent, not guaranteed; the only guarantee is `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify an `order by` for the result set of your first query then your data is not guaranteed to be ordered.

It does appear that you want to order by the minimal `id` field in your table based on `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [id] ASC)`.

**One way would be by using a `CTE` and `MIN(id)`**

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
SELECT route_id,fixcode,fixdescription, MIN(id) as minid
FROM route_fixcodes 
WHERE route_id = 995063 
GROUP BY route_id,fixcode,fixdescription
)
SELECT route_id,fixcode,fixdescription
FROM CTE
Order by minid;
```

---

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE #route_fixcodes( [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,route_id int,fixcode int,fixdescription nvarchar(255));

INSERT INTO #route_fixcodes(route_id,fixcode,fixdescription)
VALUES(995063,100,'Issue_Observed'),(995063,100,'Issue_Observed'),(995063,137,'Swap Altice One Pack')
,(995063,137,'Swap Altice One Pack'),(995063,247,'Defective CPE Equip.'),(995063,247,'Defective CPE Equip.')
,(995063,112,'outside coax repair'),(995063,112,'outside coax repair')
```

**Result**

```
route_id    fixcode fixdescription
995063  100 Issue_Observed
995063  137 Swap Altice One Pack
995063  247 Defective CPE Equip.
995063  112 outside coax repair
```

Comment: above solution doesn't work.I don't want my output in any of the order. I want output as it displayed in screenshot

Comment: thanks @Randi Vertongen for the help. there is nothing like no solution. I got the solution from above your partial query. here is my query. select route_id,fixcode,fixdescription, MIN(id) as minid from route_fixcodes where route_id = 995063   GROUP BY route_id,fixcode,fixdescription Order by minid

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select 
    route_id,fixcode as fx,fixdescription 
from 
    route_fixcodes 
group by 
    route_id,fixcode ,fixdescription 
having 
    route_id = 12345 Order by fx
```

Comment: suggestion doesn't work. Order by in last doesn't maintain my original Order.

Comment: I don't want my output in any of the order. I want output as it displayed in screenshot.

Comment: @kkakadiya, a table is an unordered set of rows. The order of data in you screen image can differ with the same data depending on how SQL server chose to return the rows. [Order by is required](https://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/) if you need data returned in a particular sequence.